# No single point of failure with Thingsboard and Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, haproxy, thingsboard

i already have some experience with Thingsboard setup, but until now i only deployed it using the standalone scenario. One Thingsboard instance with Postgres(hybrid setup) - one Cassandra.

What i want to do, is create a No Single Point of Failure installation.

My idea is to use HAproxy to switch between two Thingsboard instances and have two Cassandra instances with the same exact data.

Is it possible? If yes then how?

https://pasteboard.co/JJNhbON.png

A simple diagram of what i want to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd simplify the storage layer by deploying multiple DCs for Cassandra with each Thingsboard instance routing traffic to its own Cassandra DC. With this design, you won't have to worry about having to keep two distinct Cassandra clusters in sync.

The HA proxy can simply divert traffic to a Thingsboard instance that is operational. Cheers!

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to answer. I understand your point about HAproxy traffic diversion, it's the main reason I want to use it. 
But how am I gonna make sure that everyone has access to all the data with what you are suggesting. Maybe i did not fully uderstand (most possible scenario). Could you make a simple diagram so I can visualise better your solution? Thanks in advance!

PS I changed the diagram a bit in the link on the question

Answer (score 0):

No single point of failure configuration is:

1. Zookeeper cluster - 3 nodes
2. Kafka cluster - 3 nodes
3. Cassandra cluster- 3 nodes
4. PostgreSQL cluster - 2 nodes (master/slave) + PgPool 1 node
5. Redis cluster- 3-6 nodes
6. Thingsboard - 2 nodes (may be used as monolith or microservices)
7. Load balancer (HAproxy or other)

That will bring a real fault tolerance and the ability to scale horizontally. You can spin up a Kubernetes cluster to manage that easily. If you don't have a heavy load, you can use a shared CPU resource with Docker-compose or Kubernetes. At least 3 physical machines required in separate racks.